# Edit table values in php+ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have table which goes like this:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered" id="sample_editable_1">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                 Eventname
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                 Time
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Parsed Channel
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                 Real Channel
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                 Edit
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                 Delete
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <tr>
 <?php while ($row = $req_events_parse->fetch()) {  
  echo"<td>
                    ".$row['eventname']."
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                 ".$row['datetime']."
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                 ".$row['twchannel']."
                            </td>
                            <td class='center'>
                                 ".$row['realchannelname']."
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <a class='edit' href='javascript:;'>
                                Edit </a>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <a class='delete' href='javascript:;'>
                                Delete </a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>";
}
?>
                        </tbody>
                        </table>
```

And i have jscript which on buttonclick enables me to edit table data but only keeps it in html, main part of the script goes like this:

```
  table.on('click', '.edit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();


        var nRow = $(this).parents('tr')[0];

        if (nEditing !== null && nEditing != nRow) {

            restoreRow(oTable, nEditing);
            editRow(oTable, nRow);
            nEditing = nRow;
        } else if (nEditing == nRow && this.innerHTML == "Save") {

            saveRow(oTable, nEditing);
            nEditing = null;
            alert("Updated!");
        } else {

            editRow(oTable, nRow);
            nEditing = nRow;
        }
    });
}
```

My question is, how would i get values from row i was editing, i would like to get those values and send them to my php script which will update mysql database acordingly.

Comment: it is ok, i figured it out, my question was incomplete and while trying to fill in more on my problem i have fixed it.

var jqInputs = $('input', nRow);
            oTable.fnUpdate(jqInputs[0].value, nRow, 0, false);
            oTable.fnUpdate(jqInputs[1].value, nRow, 1, false);
            oTable.fnUpdate(jqInputs[2].value, nRow, 2, false);
            oTable.fnUpdate(jqInputs[3].value, nRow, 3, false);
            oTable.fnUpdate('<a class="edit" href="">Edit</a>', nRow, 4, false);
            oTable.fnUpdate('<a class="delete" href="">Delete</a>', nRow, 5, false);
        oTable.fnDraw();